# About __destruct() magic method and when it's invoked

Tags: php, destructor

I've a class that stores an array and save its content on `__destruct()` event. Is `__destruct()` invoked automatically when there are no other reference to the object as a "whole "or relative to the current class or script that use it? Example:

```
class Store
{
  public function set($key, $value) { $this->data[$key] = $value; }
  public function __destruct() { fwrite($this->handle, serialize($this->data)); }
}

class Consumer
{
   protected $store;
   public function __construct() { $this->store = new Store(); }
   public function __destruct() { $this->store->set('key', 'a'); }
}

// In external script...
$store = new Store();
$store->set('key', 'b');
new Consumer();
```

**When `__destruct()` is called in this example? Twice? One? What is the value of *key*?**

Comment: Any particular reason why the Consumer destruct uses `$this->store` when it doesn't exist?

Comment: @Matthew it has a reference to Store, i omitted it. See my edits.

Comment: It's still slightly unclear... are those two stores supposed to be the same? As it is now, they are different objects, so the Consumer one will not affect the global `$store` object. i.e., Consumer's will be set to a on destruct, and the global will remain 'b'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

The consumer's would be called first since it immediately has no reference. Then the store's when the script exits:

- new Store() => Store construct
- new Consumer() => Consumer construct => Store construct
- (implicit delete of Consumer) => Consumer destruct => Store destruct
- script exit => Store destruct

This is per object. Each object that is created/destroyed will have the construct/destruct methods called.

Comment: Circular references are caught in garbage collector cycles with PHP 5.3+. In the shutdown sequence this is after the shutdown handler callback (which is first) on second position.